# Установить расширение CURL

Tags: php, apache, curl, localhost

Всем привет, пытаюсь поставить опенкарт себе на локалку, но столкнулся с проблемой что CURL не активирован, в php.ini убрал `;`, скачал нужные библиотеки .dll, перезагрузил апач, но все равно ругается, в чем может быть проблема?
P.S. Система Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написанное ниже актуально для связки Windows 8.1 x64,  Windows10 x64 + Apache 2.4.12 (win32) + Open SSl 1.0.1m + PHP 5.6.11 (php-5.6.11-Win32-VC11-x86).

1. Скачиваем библиотеку cURL http://winampplugins.co.uk/curl.
   Распаковываем в любую папку. Например:
   «W:\WebServers\usr\local\curl».
2. В файле настроек PHP php.ini необходимо включить расширение extension=php_curl.dll.
3. Пункт не обязательный, но во многих источниках его рекомендуют выполнять. У меня работает без выполнения этого пункта. Из папки где установлен PHP скопировать в папку «C:\Windows\system32» следующие библиотеки: libssh2.dll, php_curl.dll (находится в папке ext), ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll. Дополнительно файл ssleay32.dll необходимо скопировать в «C:\Windows\SysWOW64».
4. Добавить в переменные среды в переменную Path пути до папки установки curl.exe и файла php.ini. Например, «W:\WebServers\usr\local\curl;W:\WebServers\usr\local\php5».